# What determines the Monk's ranged attack damage?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I've reached level 5, upgraded all main stats and even gotten a hold of an upgraded weapon, but my Monk's ranged attack always seems to be doing 8 damage. Never any more and never any less. What determines the damage of this attack and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ranged damage indicator on your weapon, looks like a bow/arrow